# SQL Server - MyCTE query based on 24 hour period (next day)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this bit of code:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CardUser ORDER BY CardTableID) AS NewVariation
    FROM   CardChecker
)
UPDATE MyCTE 
SET    Status = NewVariation
```

which currently updates the status column, however what I want to happen is over a 24 hour period, the status starts again the next day at 1, and counts again based on the *CardUser* like specified above:

Current data and what happens:

```
2   aaa 1   2015-06-25 08:00:00.000 123 1   NULL
3   ccc 1   2015-06-25 00:00:00.000 124 1   NULL
4   aaa 1   2015-06-25 17:30:00.000 125 2   NULL
5   aaa 1   2015-06-26 17:30:00.000 125 *3* NULL
```

what I want to happen:

```
2   aaa 1   2015-06-25 08:00:00.000 123 1   NULL
3   ccc 1   2015-06-25 00:00:00.000 124 1   NULL
4   aaa 1   2015-06-25 17:30:00.000 125 2   NULL
5   aaa 1   2015-06-26 17:30:00.000 125 *1* NULL
```

im not quite sure how I could add this to the above query so would it be possible for someone to point me in the right direction?

the main problem is the EventTime field contains both the date and the time, so adding it is as a PARTITION means the status would always be 1 based on the time parameter of the field

thanks for the help

**Current CardTable structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE CardTable (CardTableID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
CardUser VARCHAR(50),
CardNumber VARCHAR(50),
EventTime DATETIME,
Status INT)
```

Comment: structure of CardChecker table? Looks like you can partition on date column you have, along with CardUser

Comment: based on the date column, it also takes into consideration the time so I would want just the date to be considered, unless i need to include another column for this?

Comment: why can't you take the datepart only from datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CONVERT()` the EventTime to `DATE` type and then `PARTITION`:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT Status,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CardUser, CONVERT(DATE, EventTime) 
                             ORDER BY CardTableID) AS NewVariation
    FROM   CardChecker
)
UPDATE MyCTE 
SET    Status = NewVariation
```

Your query basically unnecessarily updating entire table everytime. If `EventTime` is current date time of the system, having a flag to mark already updated status would improve the performance.

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT Status,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CardUser, CONVERT(DATE, EventTime) 
                             ORDER BY CardTableID) AS NewVariation
    FROM   CardChecker
    WHERE  Status IS NULL OR
           CONVERT(DATE, EventTime) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
)
UPDATE MyCTE 
SET    Status = NewVariation
```

Comment: in terms of this flag mark... is this simply another column in the database or an additional field I can add within the procedure?

Comment: It has to be a field in the table. If `Status` column value is `0` or `null` before the update you could use the same `Status` column without adding a new one.

Comment: it will inserted into the table as a null, so this will work perfect! thanks for the help, I was so close, wrote the CONVERT part wrong.. Thanks again